# Android. Gradient Image is displayed incorrectly

Tags: android, user-interface

I have got another mysterious issue. So, I am setting a background image for LinearLayout. This image contains gradient. Don't know why, but after I launch application the image appears to consist of several parts that actually form "smooth transition" of gradient, and that's why it seems that background image is not a gradient.

Could you please advice how to fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you could point to a screenshot so we can see what you mean? Either take a screenshot of the emulator, or use the DDMS tool (which is also available inside Eclipse).

Comment: Also, let us know image format & size and how are you specifying dimensions of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator and many Android phones use a 16bit color palette. 65536 colors may not be enough to smoothly display your gradient.

Comment: This resolved my issue. I have updated background's image color palette and everything works :). Thanks.